# What training is appropriate to get to help students deal with stress?

Tags: emotional-responses

I often have undergraduate students in my office who are clearly under considerable stress.  These students are usually first years who are making the transition from high school.  This goes beyond the "school is lots of work" stress into the "I'm about to break down" level.  The university does have a counselling service that I almost always refer the students to, but they are often booked up and it takes a while to get an appointment.

I am not interested in becoming a therapist, but I would like to know some techniques for helping students through this sort of problem when they are in my office.  Things like how to get a student to calm down and how to get them to start working to solve their problems.

What types of training should I seek out to help me with this?  I'm not even sure what the right field of study is, so I'd be starting from scratch...

Comment: These are undergraduates, specifically first years making the transition from high school.  I agree there is something that isn't right - it's an *extremely* high stress environment.  The university is taking great steps to handle it, but the initiatives are slow to take effect

Comment: Surely a large part of the solution is that the University needs to expand the counselling services as if it takes a "while" to get an appointment that may not be appropriate in some cases...

Comment: I certainly agree that there are systemic issues.  The university really is taking great strides in this regard, but big changes take time.  I'm really more interested in how I deal with the immediate problem of helping a student through a short bout of extreme stress

Comment: If they're close to breakdown, maybe some of the "crisis intervention" techniques would help - e.g. [this list](https://patient.info/doctor/crisis-intervention#nav-2). It seems to boil down to 1) identify what the problem is 2) ask what they're doing about it 3) give them feedback to improve that plan until they have a good plan A 4) also discuss plan B and C so they don't have to be afraid their life will be ruined if plan A doesn't go smoothly.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but my instincts tell me that the best answer is along the lines of "just send troubled students to any available counseling services provided at your institution."

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, but the problem is that available counselling services are full. I hate just sending students away with a vague hope that one day someone will see them

Comment: Many of these students will be covered by their parents' health insurance, so in principle they could go to an off-campus provider.  Also they can see a medical doctor.  Here's another idea -- how about alerting a department administrator?  I wonder if your department's grad students have put together a peer advising program?  A healthy, supportive department helps new students build a support network.  Helping set up the infrastructure for healthy interactions within the department could be a worthwhile investment of your time.

Answer (score 4):

It is admirable that you are trying to address this on your own, but I would recommend *not* trying to solve it yourself by trying to find resources. There are complex ethical and legal (like FERPA in the US) issue.

There are likely other faculty, staff, other students who find themselves in the same situation -- wanting to know what to do but not knowing where to go to learn. Graduate students also often find themselves in this position when teaching undergraduates

So why not try to address that issue for all of these groups? You say that your university has a counseling service. So why not ask that service if they would put on a one-day or half-day training course for any university member who desires to learn how to respond appropriately to students in need. My university does this, and it has been extremely successful. They even have separate sessions depending on the context in which you interact with students.